# How to dynamically generate an code and create intellisense dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums

We would like to be able to read a list of values from a table (ie: List of Error Codes) and dynamically create a class contains an enum for the list.  I would then like to be able to use Intellisense to access the enum. I have found this article on the [EnumBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder.aspx) class, but I want to save the dynamically generated enum to the current project I am in so it is part of the project not a separate dll.  Is there a way to use the EnumBuilder class and save it to a code file (C#) instead of dll.

We would want to do the following automatically in VS, when a project is created or opened.

1. Created a new file if it does not exist.
2. Update the file if there have been any changes.

I know I probably need to create a VS plugin to create/upgrade the enum.  So any suggestions on good articles to read on creating VS plugin would be a good starting point.

Comment: Searching for tools/libraries/articles is off-topic on SO... I'd recommend starting with command line tool (or maybe MSBuild task) that generates/update files you want (unless your goal is learn how to create VS plugins).